# query the size of an mmap() allocation

Tags: linux, posix, mmap

I have code which will be compiled with Win32 and POSIX. With Win32 I use VirtualAlloc, with posix I use mmap(). With Win32 I won't have to remember the size of the allocation for VirtualFree. But mmap reqires a size-argument equal to the size of the allocated region in my case. Currently I'm remembering the size with a size_t-varibable at the beginning of the region. But is it possible to query the size of an mmap()ed allocated region with a pointer to the beginning?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does munmap needs a length as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076308/why-does-munmap-needs-a-length-as-parameter)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate because there may be means to query the size of mmap()ed region.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, Linux does not keep a record of individual `mmap` calls.